# Java - Ignore warnings on directory/package level

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, warnings

Some of our code is auto-generated (by Apache Axis) and it reports a ton of warnings. An example would be:

```java
private java.util.HashMap faultExceptionNameMap = new java.util.HashMap();
```

Here, the warning would be

> HashMap is a raw type. References to generic type HashMap should be parameterized.

Of course it makes no sense to actually address these warnings, as we have to trust Apache Axis anyway and it would simply re-create the code as-is again.

Because our team uses different IDEs, from VSCode to IntelliJ IDEA to Eclipse, I'm looking for an IDE-agnostic way to exclude warnings coming from the auto-generated package/directory. It would be best if this option could be set for the workspace by being under version control.

In TypeScript, I'd set an `exclude` array in `tsconfig.json`

Does Java, for example, have an equivalent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i only find this way to solve the issue now:

add `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")` to your method or variable like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private java.util.HashMap faultExceptionNameMap = new java.util.HashMap();
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend adding the @SuppressWarnings to the auto-generated code after its generated:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-replacer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
   <executions>
    <execution>
     <phase>prepare-package</phase>
     <goals>
     <goal>replace</goal>
     </goals>
     </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
    <includes>
      <include>target/generated-sources/apache/blahblah//*.java</include>
    </includes>

   <regex>true</regex>
   <regexFlags>
    <regexFlag>MULTILINE</regexFlag>
   </regexFlags>

  <replacements>
   <replacement>
     <token>^(@SuppressWarnings\(.*?\)\s+)?public class</token>
   <value>@SuppressWarnings("all") public class</value>
    </replacement>
   </replacements>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The configuration above would essentially do this through maven. If you have other build tools you would do something similar.